# The button tag's form attribute causes the page reload?

Tags: php, ajax, html

First,this is my AJAX code:

```
<script>
function ajaxInsert() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("select").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText
    }
  }
  var user = document.getElementById("user").value
  var pwd = document.getElementById("pwd").value
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value
  var str = "user=" + user + "&pwd=" + pwd + "&email=" + email
  // document.write(str)
  xmlhttp.open("post", "getconnectforxmlhttp.php", true)
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  xmlhttp.send(str)
}
```

and then,my form:

```
<form method="post" id="insertform">
  <label for="user">用户名</label><input type="text" id="user" name="user">
  <label for="pwd">密码</label><input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd">
  <label for="email">邮箱</label><input type="email" id="email" name="email">
</form>
<button form="insertform" onclick="ajaxInsert()">提交</button>
<div id="select"></div>
```

and last,my php code in the getconnectforxmlhttp.php file:

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=db_test", "root", "");
if (isset($_POST)) {
  $values = "'".implode("', '", array_values($_POST))."'";
}
$str = "";
try {
  $resp = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO user (user, pwd, email) VALUES    ($values)");
  $resp->execute();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  $str .= "Error".$e->getMessage()."<br>";
}
if ($pdo->lastInsertId()) {
  try {
    $res = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM user");
    $res->execute();
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    $str .= "Error".$e->getMessage()."<br>";
  }
  $result = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  for ($i=0; $i < count($result); ++$i) {
    $str .= $result[$i]["id"]."&nbsp;".$result[$i]["user"]."&nbsp;"
    .$result[$i]["pwd"]."&nbsp;".$result[$i]["email"]."<br>";
  }
  echo $str;
} else {
  $str .= "插入失败";
  echo $str;
}

?>
```

What it do is insert a new row into my table user in the local database,and then show them all between the div tag.but when I run this code,the insert statement successes,and the result(between the div tag) shows a second,yes,it do shows,but strangely,then it's gone,disappeared.Now I know how to do it right,simply delete the form attribute in the start button tag,and change the value of id of the div tag into something else,like:

```
<button  onclick="ajaxInsert()">提交</button>
<div id="sel"></div>
```

also change AJAX code a little like `document.getElementById("sel").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText`,but with a little problem:I don't know what happened,what's the problem of the form I wrote in the first place,what the changes solve the problem?

Comment: This is an unclear question. You are asking about many things. What actaully is your problem?

Comment: @CharlieWalton I think I described below the codes,something happened and it's the button's form attribute to blame,but I don't know why,so I asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive you are asking why you page will refresh when you click the button instead of running your javascript. This is probably because the button is linked to the form with its `form` attribute. This isn't the standard way to submit a form.

A HTML form requires a `action` and `method` attribute to submit. Without an `action` attribute the form will default to submit to the same page, **which would explain a page refresh**.

Although you intend for your form to submit using AJAX, What happens if your JavaScript breaks? What happens if your user doesn't have JavaScript enabled? In both situations your form can not submit.

Also, a HTML form is submitted using a input of type `submit`. This means you form may look like this;

```
<form method="post" action="getconnectforxmlhttp.php"  onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); ajaxInsert();" id="insertform">
  <label for="user">用户名</label><input type="text" id="user" name="user">
  <label for="pwd">密码</label><input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd">
  <label for="email">邮箱</label><input type="email" id="email" name="email">
  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="html">
  <input type="submit" value="提交">
</form>
<div id="select"></div>
```

If this form submits without AJAX then it will submit all of its data to `getconnectforxmlhttp.php`. The input `<input type="hidden" name="return" value="html">` will allow you to know that there is no JavaScript and the PHP should return a HTML page to display the data.

Otherwise your AJAX submits to the PHP file **without** the hidden input. In this case you PHP file can return just the data.

For users with JavaScript enabled the form attribute onsubmit will be used;

```
 onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); ajaxInsert();"
```

This will first stop the form submitting normally, and then call your function to submit the form using AJAX.

This aproach towards JavaScript is called progressive enhancement, it allows your system to **work** for everyone but work better where posible. This is favoured rather than to make it **not work** for everyone but work better for some people

Comment: I appreciate your answer and patience.Thanks a lot,the answer is more than I asked,thank you very much.